# How do I make $y$ the subject so I can differentiate $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus

> For example, to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of equations such as
>
> 1. $x^2 \sin y + y^2 = \sqrt{x+y}$
> 2. $ \ln y = \sin x \ln x$

I need to isolate the $y$ or make $y$ the subject before we can differentiate. How do I do that?

I looked up online and saw that I need to do an "implicit differentiation", how does that work for these equations?

Comment: It's clear on how to isolate $y$ in 2. Otherwise, implicit differentiation is just an extension of the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me take a simpler example. 
Suppose the equation is $\ln y + xy = y + \sin x$

Now you differentiate the LHS and RHS both wrt $x$. Assume $y$ to be a function of $x$ rather than a constant.

For LHS, $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln y + xy) = \frac{d}{dx}(\ln y) + \frac{d}{dx}(xy) = \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} + x\frac{dy}{dx} + y $

For RHS,  $\frac{d}{dx}(y + \sin x) = \frac{dy}{dx} + \cos x  $

Equality is maintained under differentiation wrt the same variable. Hence we can write

$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} + x\frac{dy}{dx} + y  = \frac{dy}{dx} + \cos x  $ 
$ \implies \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}  + x\frac{dy}{dx}  - \frac{dy}{dx} = \cos x - y  $ 
$ \implies  \frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{y} + x  - 1 \right) = (\cos x - y)  $ 
$ \implies  \frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{(\cos x - y)}{\left(\frac{1}{y} + x  - 1 \right)}  $

This is all you can get via implicit differentiation. It is in general not possible to eliminate the $y$ from the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

Since the relationship between x and y are so intertwined, these problems can be solved by using implicit derivation. Simply put, implicit derivation allows one to find the derivative of a function, but requires input of both x and y.

Just take the derivative of the whole function, but every time you take the derivative of y, multiply that term by dy/dx

For example,

$\ln y = \sin x \ln x \\ \frac 1y \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {\sin x}x+\ln x \cos x \\\frac{dy}{dx}=y({\frac{sin x}x}+{\ln x \cos x})$

Now input x and y to find the derivative at a point.

Hint: if you only have an x value, go back to the original function to solve for the y value.

Comment: Really Nice answer!